# How to avoid displaying newsletter form if it is submitted or close once?

Tags: forms, mautic

I am using mautic form.
I have added form code in my header script and this script always run on every page so how can I avoid to display that form if user close form or he has submitted it before.

Answer (score 0):

Paste the script to the content of your page where you want the form to display. That way it will appear only on the page you want it to show up and on the place you want it to show up.

If you want to display another content after the form submission, configure the after submit redirect URL in the form's configuration.